# Thisworkbook.Path / Activeworkbook.Path returns "" on some devices

Tags: excel, vba

I have a short VBA code to check the current file location.
Due to security reasons the file should always be on our network drive.

The strange part is, that on some devices the current path is "" ?

Code:

```
'----------CHECK FILE LOCATION----------------------
If ThisWorkbook.Path = "\\Exampledrive\Examplefolder\test" Then

Else
    MsgBox ("Security Issue, file will be removed"), vbCritical
    ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
    Kill ThisWorkbook.FullName
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End If
```

Many thanks!

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Path` always returns a `vbNullString` (same as `""`) if the workbook is a new workbook (or eg. an unsaved copy of an existing workbook) that was never saved before. Because how can it know the path you are going to save it later on?

Comment: Are you sure that `ThisWorkbook.Path =""`. Can you add this line `Msgbox Thisworkbook.path` before the `If` condition?

Comment: @Peh , indeed but the file is saved on the net-drive. Is there another way to find where the users opened the file?

Comment: @SiddharthRout , yes that's how I found out that Thisworkbook.Path is returning "" or like 'Peh' said above 'vbNullString'

Comment: That is strange. I have never come across this scenario (assuming that the file was opened from the networkpath)

Comment: If I open an existing workbook from a network path and run `debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Path` I get something like `\\servername\shareddrive\folder\ `. Asking again … (1) are you sure that `ThisWorkbook.Path` is empty? Please verify! The code in your question does not show that you verify this. (2) Which server OS and client OS are you using when it is empty? (3) How is it opened? From a file explorer? Via browser (Intranet) link?

Comment: I have the same problem. Network file. Need to to check the path of the file that has been opened. Can't save the file beforehand to use .path